# Configuring Android Support Dependencies library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am trying to build my project on device and having problem with library configuration for App-v7-appcompact from the screenshot as below.

[image: Problem Image on Eclipse]

I have successfully added App-v7-appcompact into Eclipse project and also tried adding manually in Eclipse folder but having same errors even I added to build path aswell. I dont know what is problem with Appcompact-v7-library, plz help me in fixing my issue so I am able to run application on device.

I also added libraries in properties aswell.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check here this is very helpfull http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html